# Google Chrome - Extension issues

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently developing a chrome Extension and i wanted to know, how it's possible to put more then one button on a Extension. Because when i add for instance 2 reference on the manifest.json, it only display the last one.

I also wanted to now how it's possible to add an input text instead if a button.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible, you can only add one browser action per extension. If your extension requires two browser actions, you should deploy two extension, where one of the extensions depends on the origin.

You can use [chrome.extension.onRequestExternal.addListener](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#event-onRequestExternal) to listen for external requests coming from your extension, and send messages between them with: [chrome.extension.sendRequest](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-sendRequest)

Hope that helped!

Comment: But how can you explain that the toolbar developer, can put a lot of components like a button, search input text,... And all of these elements are considerered as only ONE Extensions. So i suppose it's possible ?

And about a text input instead of a button, you don't really answerd to me, you just show me how to communicate :)

Comment: Well, You cannot put multiple buttons on the toolbar in one extension :) You need to change your design and once you open a (browser action) popup, you can see multiple buttons (toolbar for your extension). That is by design for Google Chrome.

You cannot use a text input in the extension toolbar either. If you want, you can create a toolbar as a content script that gets injected in every page, but that is distracting to the user. The majority of Chrome users would rather like a browser action, that is how the Google Chrome UI is about that millions love :)